# webpack must be known

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll

I am trying to use ion infinite scroll directive

above is the link which is similar to the functionality for what i need to do

Comment: Are you installing that module for any particular reason? Because Ionic already has one for that https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/

Comment: @ManuelObregozo yes i am doing for the same purpose and i didnt knew ionic have one and do i need to install it or it has that directive?

Comment: No, nothing. It is included inside ionic lib.

Comment: ya i have tried it but the function isnt triggering when at bottom of the page

Comment: update your answer with your code, html and controller.

Answer (score 0):

Instead to install this new directive, why don't use the native `ion-infinite-scroll` of Ionic? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/

The `ion-infinite-scroll` directive allows you to call a function whenever the user gets to the bottom of the page or near the bottom of the page.
This is much easy to use:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll
    on-infinite="loadMore()"
    distance="1%">
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

I hope that helps!

Greetings.

Comment: I have tried it but it is not triggering the function loadMore() when the scroll is near to the bottom of the page

Comment: Great! Please take a few minutes to review the information and docs provided before to copy & paste in your project. This function "loadMore()" needs to be declared on your controller. The on-infinite expression only fires the function defined when the scroller reaches the bottom. Do you understand?

Comment: yes i understood that but it is not happening in that way

Answer (score 0):

You need to track when you've not more record ..with something like  a bool var and also on back end you need a pagination :

```
function _fetchProducts() {
            if (vm.end) return;

            Product.GetSearch(searchFilter).$promise.then(function (resp) {
                if (resp.length) {
                    searchFilter.skip += searchFilter.take;

                        vm.products.concat(resp);
                    });
                }
                else vm.end = true;

                //result ready
                vm.prodReady = true;
                $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log("Failed to download list items:", err);
                $cordovaToast.show('Errore .. riprovare piu tardi!', 'long', 'center');
                vm.end = true;
            }).finally(function () {
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
            });

        }
```

And in you HTML:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!partnerproduct.end" ng-hide="true" on-infinite="fetchMoreProducts()" distance="1%">
                        </ion-infinite-scroll>
```